# C Comparing Array Elements with a String

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm attempting to write a piece of code to list possible words when given a scrambled word as a user input, so basically an unscrambler.  I want to know any effective method to read in an input from the user (scanf, getchar(), etc.) and how to compare it to words in a wordlist text file.

My initial idea was to scan the user input, break it down in an array and list the number of letters, for example, the word "etst" would register with e = 1, s = 1, t = 2.  I would then scan in words line by line from the text file, match the string length (4), compare it with the user input (etst) and then output any word with the same letters in the array, resulting in the found word: "test".

Another example:
Input: "emta",
a = 1, e = 1, m = 1, t = 1,
strlen = 4,
compare with wordlist,
Output(s): team, meat, mate, tame.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Show Code!   (and ask a *question*; *"Any help"* is not a **question**)

Comment: Your logic is fine but you can't ask us to write your code for you. If you're wondering perhaps where to get started I would look at first reading from files, then using the strcmp function in c. The rest is pretty explanatory.

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstandings, I am not showing code, nor wanting others to write it for me (nowhere have I asked this), I am merely requesting a guide to helping me understand the situation and how I would implement such a complex idea (for me) and seeing different techniques for an approach to my program.  I already know the functions (if not I can read into it myself) but there are many different ways to solve this as I have already discovered.  I want to see if there are any other options which may be available to me which might make my life easier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find the anagrams of the string and then check with strcmp() functin with all the words in the file.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, your anagram method made my life so much easier.  Didn't even have to compare strings with strcmp()!

Answer (score 0):

This is a question which is often asked in interviews. There are multiple ways to solve this problem.

Your approach is basically correct.

Let's see what are the benefits of different approach.

1) **HashCode:** If you find a way where you can generate unique code for unique words of combination of unequal characters, you can always equate their hashcode to find if the given word stands for some word in your word list. For example: if you have  Input: "emta", "a = 1, e = 1, m = 1, t = 1" is already a hascode of counts of each charachter and then the following words "team, meat, mate, tame" gives you the same hashcode. So you can equate the hascodes to match the words. This solution is O(n).

2) **Sorting:** You can sort your input word and match it with all words in your word list sorted. The sorting algorithm which you choose is upto you but shouldn't be bubblesort.

Likewise there are other ways to solve this problem but one thing is true that you would already need a list of valid english words from before hand to solve this problem, thus, you will also need a hashtable for quick access of those words. In case of HashCode the key of the HashTable can be HashCode itself and in case of sorting the word length or sorted word itself.

You can think of other solutions too based on different data structures available. One solution could be using a Binary Tree and keeping the character count in it's node. This will again be a O(n) solution.